# Salat serialisation error

Tags: scala, salat

I'm currently having issues with Salat. Hope you guys can help me!

Here's the case class that is driving me crazy:

```
object UserDAO extends SalatDAO[User, ObjectId](
  collection = DB("users") //Returns the "users" MongoCollection
)

case class User(
  _id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  screenName: String,
  phoneNumber: PhoneNumber,
  validated: Boolean = false)
```

**PhoneNumber** is an instance of type **com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonenumber$PhoneNumber** (I'm using libphonenumber)

This is my custom transformer:

```
class PhoneNumberTransformer extends CustomTransformer[PhoneNumber, String] {
  val phoneNumberUtils = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance()
  def deserialize(b: String) = phoneNumberUtils.parse(b, "UK")
  def serialize(a: PhoneNumber) = phoneNumberUtils.format(a, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
}
```

This is my custom context:

```
package object model {

  implicit val ctx = new Context {
    val name = "Custom Salat Context"
  }

  ctx.registerCustomTransformer(new PhoneNumberTransformer)

}
```

If I try to insert a new User document using UserDAO, I get this exception:

```
project java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonenumber$PhoneNumber
project     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:284)
project     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:185)
project     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:131)
project     at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:33)
[...]
```

Any idea on how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but `PhoneNumber` is a Java public static class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salat developer here.  I'm not familiar with libphonenumber but this is most likely breaking down because it looks like you're trying to serialize an inner class.

Something to try.  If you copy pasted the `PhoneNumber` class to the top level of a local package (not inside an object, trait, or class), extending the relevant class/interface that bring the i18n goodness, and changed the type param to point at this class instead, does it work?

If so, the problem is that Salat doesn't support inner classes.  If not, we'll have to look further.

Comment: Doesn't work. I went through libphonenumber docs and I discovered that `PhoneNumber` class is an inner class and it's also being generated using protobuf. A lethal mix of things :D. Thanks for your help! I'll save the number as a string for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize Java classes directly to Salat. You need to write either a custom salat serializer or write `PhoneNumber` as a case class